# How To Display Custom Frontend Popup Message As Response From The Backend NodeJS Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want to display a popup as express Response.
I have made the popup in the front end.
Here is the code.

Index.html

```
<div class="aws" id="aws">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
        <p>تم إضافة الكلمة إلى القاموس بنجاح.</p>
        <button onclick="closeaws()">حسنا</button>
</div>
```

Index.js

```
let aws = document.getElementById('aws');
async function openaws(){
    aws.classList.add('openaws'); // This set the popup visibility: visible; if the function is called
}
```

app.js

```
app.post('', (request, response) => {
    let sampleFile;
    let uploadPath;

    if (!request.files) {
        return response.status(400).send('No file was uploaded.');

    }

    sampleFile = request.files.sampleFile;
    uploadPath = __dirname + '/img/' + sampleFile.name;

    console.log(sampleFile);

    sampleFile.mv(uploadPath, err => {
        if(err) return response.status(500).send(err);

        //I want the display the popup if this condition is true
        //In other words call the openaws() function but that will not work obviously
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide the whole index.html file? Or at least the form/js that submits the file. There are a couple of ways to  achieve that and this information narrows it down

Comment: I can't add the whole idex.html stackoverflow dont accept that, I made a <form action="/" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the submit event from the form and make a post request with `fetch`. That way you can capture the response and handle it appropriately.

index.js

```
let aws = document.getElementById("aws");
function openaws() {
    aws.classList.add("openaws");
}
function closeaws() {
    aws.classList.remove("openaws");
}

const form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch("/", {
        method: "POST",
        body: new FormData(e.target),
    }).then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
            openaws();
        } else if (res.status > 300) {
            res.text().then((text) => {
                // handle error
                console.warn(text);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You also need to always return some response from the server

app.js

```
...
sampleFile.mv(uploadPath, (err) => {
    if (err) return response.status(500).send(err);

    return response.status(200).send("Ok");
});
...
```